# Best approach to creating a component presents data in differing formats

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I was thinking about creating a control that could display hierarchical data either as a table or as a list. I'm thinking that I would like to create two data attributes:

1. data-display= "table/list"
2. data-source = "http://..."

I can think of two ways that I could go about creating the component.

1) **As an angular directive** which could load in multiple partial views.

Whilst the Angular approach would be quite clean and simple I'm not sure how I would go about changing the partial view or a directive based on a data attribute.

2) **As a CSS style** on a ul element. I could use the CSS to render either a  or  as a table. I feel that this could get messy through!

I am a little unsure as to which approach would be best for solving this problem. I just wanted to put this out there to see what the community thought would be the best approach before I begin researching.

Comment: Why do you need it? For example, responsive design I would go with CSS mostly. Displaying same data in different forms - directive would be nice, etc...

Comment: The is an request for opinions and so off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Paulie_D Do you really think that this is off topic? I'm asking for guides as to best practices. Whether or not they exist and how one would go about solving the problem. If you think about it most of the questions on SO could be classified as off topic in that case.

Comment: Who decides on "best" practices?...there's no overall rulebook and so you will get different opinions ("what the community thinks")...and so it's off-topic.